# Error in setting output video settings

Tags: ios, xcode, avcapturesession

```
output.videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
    forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];
```

I get this error on this particular line

```
No known class method for selector "dictionaryWithObject:forKey:
```

Any reason for this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
videoOutput.videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA], (id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey,
                             nil];
```

Comment: Strange! This works! If possible can you suggest any reason for these types of errors? :)

Comment: I don't have idea, maybe some compilator error. This also works for me (i don't have any compilator errors): videoOutput.videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA] forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];